# When is a javascript code executed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I have this code :

```
 <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    func1();
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    func2();
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="tabber.js"></script>
 </head>
```

Would func2() be called only after jquery.js is completely loaded? Basically I am trying to make a progress bar in a page with some heavy javascript code. So I want to know how much of the page has loaded.Now I can show this progress in the form of the number of js files that have been completely downloaded. So if func2() is called only after jquery completely loads, I can use that function to slide up the progress bar by some percentage.

Comment: You can't have Javascript code directly in <head>... fix your example.

Comment: You could use something like this: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex11/xpprogressbar.htm

Comment: Also, it's better not to load JQuery locally, but obtain it from a 3rd party source (e.g. using Google Libraries API http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html ).

Comment: Its just an example, people. I used jquery.js just to mean any js file. I just wanted to know what will be the sequence of execution ?

Comment: @RDL : This one is just an animation . I want to show the amount of page data that has been loaded. Like the one we get before going into our gmail inbox. (Hope you've used gmail)

Comment: You could load everything javascript.  This would allow you to track how many things need to load and once each item is loaded increase a counter.  From that you can calculate a percentage and update the progress bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScripts in a page will be executed immediately while the page loads into the browser.  The exception is when it's told to fire on an event (ie: click, after page load, etc)

If you want to ensure code is run only after the page is loaded you can use:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" 
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    [code to run once page loaded here]
  }
</script>
</head>
```

Note: put your Javascript in  tags as well.

Comment: Aren't you forgetting something?  Like loading jQuery before attempting to use it for its `ready` function?

Comment: indeed.  nice catch. jQuery load added

Answer (score 2):

None of those would ever be called because they are not in `<script>` tags.

What you probably want is to load all your scripts that are needed, and then use the `window.onload` or jQuery's `ready` event to trigger the functions you want to call.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="tabber.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            func1();
            func2();
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: Oops, I guess we had a race condition back there. I downvoted while in my screen there were no script tags, but apparently you had already edited the answer... Now I can't undo the downvote. :(